# Appending OS MasterMap feature class to the feature class in PostgreSQL database

Tags: qgis, postgresql, merge, append, os-mastermap

I have my Enterprise geodatabase as PostgreSQL. I want to keep OS MasterMap data on the geodatabase and would like to update it whenever a new tile is downloaded. However, I am struggling to find a way to to append the existing OS MasterMap feature class with new data. I tried OS Translator II in QGIS as the OS Master Map files come with .gz extension but it overwrites the existing feature class in the geodatabase.

Could you give me pointers as to how this can be done? Would I need a Python script or shall I first convert OS MasterMap data into shapefiles every time and then think about adding it to the existing OS MasterMap through ArcGIS.

I would preferably like the solution in QGIS as most of my team-mates have ArcGIS Basic license except me who has ArcGIS Standard license.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ogr2ogr to load data, you can simply apply the append tag.

```
-append
```

Other than that it will depend on the solution you are using.

The more common solutions for loading MasterMap data are:

- [Go Loader](http://www.snowflakesoftware.com/products/goloader/features/)
- [FME](https://www.safe.com/fme/fme-desktop/)

Comment: I have looked into both of these options but they are quite expensive. Is this functionality not at all possible using Open Source ???